# Are there (highly) restricted process calculi? Perhaps similar to formal grammar?

Tags: reference-request, formal-grammars, process-algebras

I've started to read about [process calculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus) (such as [CSP](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf) and [π-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus)). It seems to me that they are extremely general and can represent pretty much any concurrent system, many of which will be unable to "make progress".

I wondered if there were much more restrictive formalisms for describing concurrent processes? Perhaps something close to formal languages augmented with a parallel composition (a kind of tensor product of the joined languages) might work quite well? Maybe, in particular a [Parsing expression grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar).

Process calculi seem to generally have a concept of channels on which synchronous messages are exchanged. The set of allowable messages are known as the alphabet of a process, and it seems analogous to the symbol set of a formal language (you'd need to augment the symbols with a send and a receive label).

The possible traces of a process calculus would be analogous to the possible strings of a language.

So, **the actual questions**: is there something like this in the research literature? Thanks!

Comment: There are many typing systems for process caluculi -- [session types](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/abcd) being the most well-known example. Is this not what you have in mind?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure, but it looks interesting – I'll have a read!

Comment: This definitely looks like an interesting avenue, thank you. I'm particularly interested in interactive GUI applications. I think current formalisms are lacking in this area. Session Types seem to have developed from concurrent network protocols, but perhaps the approach could also benefit GUI.

Comment: Yes, the technology also works for interactive GUI applications, see work on session types for event-driven programming like [this](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rhu/sessionj.html). But see also [The Essence of Event-Driven Programming](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~nk480/essence-of-events.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

> I wondered if there were much more restrictive formalisms for describing concurrent processes?

[Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net) are IMO more restrictive than the process calculus and such. They are [state-transition systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_system), which are pretty much like [formal grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) (like parsing expression grammars). They all boil down to states and rules / transitions. Petri nets include [parallel composition](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/victor.khomenko/papers/PID1762231.pdf).